# Rails/React.js: How to avoid duplicate computation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, architecture, structure, dry

I have a Rails application with a React.js frontend. 
The user can upload a file containing some JSON data, and my application will read the data and display some statistics in nice graphs to the user based on the data.

I also need an API that will take in a request with JSON data, do the same computations to get the same statistics and return back a file to the user in a format specified in the request (say YAML or JSON or plain text).

The question is, where exactly do I do the computations ?

If I do them on the Frontend somewhere in my components, then I have to write similar logic on the backend so that the API can return the stats.

On the other hand since I am not saving anything to a database, it doesn't really make sense to create a model where the computations are done.

Not sure what the proper structure is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you need to expose a raw API, having logic on the server-side in your Rails app is inevitable. From the details you gave, it seems that your main consideration should probably be to avoid duplicating business logic. That leaves just one solution: **put your calculation code in your Rails backend, and expose it via API**.

The fact that you're not saving anything to a database is fine. It is typical for a server to be responsible for performing operations and not storing any kind of persistent state. If this weren't the case, we would be relying on client-side code to be performing substantial computations all over the place - meaning people's local machines would be trying to munge things like big data all through the browser; very impractical.

Once you've built the API on the server side, leverage those API endpoints from within your React app. The flow could look something like:

1. User clicks upload file
2. React app takes file, reads the data in it
3. React app takes relevant data, calls API endpoint(s) on Rails app to perform calculations
4. React app takes the responses and puts together those pretty graphs

Comment: Great , thanks. In that case do you think it makes a difference in a Rails app specifically where I put the actual functions that do the computations? In the controller ? or do I make a model, say Calculator, that would do those ?

Comment: I only have a little experience with Rails itself, but from an MVC perspective, you'll want to keep your calculations (business logic) in a model. Your "controller" will handle the communication aspects of React app <-> Rails model (i.e. the REST API endpoint).